Construct plot of $exp(1/z)$
I want to plot the function $f(z) = e^\frac{1}{z}$ in 3 forms:
First to be a plot like [this][1]. But I want to show legend of both magnitude and imaginary part scales.
Second to be a plot only with $\operatorname{arg}(f(z))$.
Third to be a plot only with $|f(z)|$.
I found that author of the photo from the link says:

Visible domain:  $[ −0.7, 0.7] \times[-0.7,0.7]$.
The hue represents the complex argument:
$\operatorname{hue}(z) = \operatorname{arg} (z)$.
The luminance represents the absolute value. After some
experimentation, I chose the following luminance mapping: $\operatorname {luminance} (z)=\operatorname {atan} (\ln(|z|^{0.6}))$.

I've never worked with Mathematica, but I've tried
ComplexPlot[Exp[1/z], {z, -0.5 - 0.5  I, 0.5 + 0.5  I},
PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, Below]]

and observed that image is very low quality.
[1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_singularity#/media/File:Essential_singularity.png

Only a starting point. ComplexPlot[Exp[1/z], {z, .7}, ColorFunction -> {Hue[#8] &, None},   RasterSize -> 500]

You can play with options and color function.
ComplexPlot[Exp[1/z],{z,-0.5-0.5  I,0.5+0.5  I},
      PlotLegends->Placed[Automatic,Below],PlotPoints->500,
      MaxRecursion->24,ColorFunction->{Hue[#8+0.5]&,None}]


Compare to
ComplexPlot[Exp[1/z],{z,-0.5-0.5  I,0.5+0.5  I},PlotLegends- >Placed[Automatic,Below]]


Reference:
Higher resolution on a complex plot

Thanks! It's beautiful. I need that in center to have that black and white colors to show that there is an essential singularity. Can you help me please?

Depending on what you are trying to emphasize, change the ColorFunction
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

Manipulate[
 ComplexPlot[
  Exp[1/z], {z, -0.5 - 0.5  I, 0.5 + 0.5  I},
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {Re[z], Im[z]}),
  PlotLabel -> Style[StringForm["`` = ``", f[z], Exp[1/z]], 18],
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic,
    LegendLabel -> Style[Arg[z], 14],
    LegendMarkerSize -> 300],
  PlotPoints -> 500,
  MaxRecursion -> 15,
  ColorFunction -> cf],
 {{cf, "CyclicLogAbsArg", "ColorFunction"}, {Automatic, "MaxAbs", 
   "LocalMaxAbs", "GlobalAbs", "QuantileAbs",
   "CyclicLogAbs", "CyclicArg", "CyclicLogAbsArg", "CyclicReImLogAbs",
   "ShiftedCyclicLogAbs", None}},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False,
 TrackedSymbols :> {cf}]


